# make run isn't executing my code

Tags: cmake

1. I write a CMakeLists.txt simple code as follows:

   cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 2.6)
   project (Tutorial)
   add_executable (Tutorial tutorial.cc)
2. I execute `cmake CMakeLists.txt` and it was done without errors and Makefiles appear.
3. Then I do the following steps:

   `make` done without errors.
   Then `make run` but it gives this error: `make: *** No rule to make target 'run'.  Stop.`

[image: Picture for all steps done]

Comment: Perhaps this is what you're looking for? [cmake “make run”](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9352300/4440445)

Answer (score 0):

`make` doesn't start programms. You generate a executable named `Tutorial`

To start it use

```
./Tutorial
```

You can see the file using `ls`

This is not an question on ubuntu. Use stackoverflow for programming questions